# How to delete blank valued keys from nested association?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, associations

Considering we have:

```
acs = <|"A" -> <|"a" -> "    ", "aa" -> "asd"|>, "B" -> <|"bb" -> "  "|>|>
```

How can we come to have a result as:

```
res = <|"A" -> <| "aa" -> "asd"|>|>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[Association@KeyValueMap[#1->DeleteCases[#2,_?(StringMatchQ[ToString@#,Whitespace..]&)]&,acs],_?(#==<||>&)]
```

Comment: Hello Alexey, good to see you here! +1.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution, based on pattern matching in the list of rules of the association:

```
acs //. x_Association :> Normal[x]
DeleteCases[ %, (key_->val_String) /; StringMatchQ[val, " "..], Infinity]
DeleteCases[ %, _->{}]
% /. List->Association

(*
{A->{a->    ,aa->asd},B->{bb->  }}
{A->{aa->asd},B->{}}
{A->{aa->asd}}
<|A-><|aa->asd|>|>
*)
```